# Why did GM Godena resign in this position?

Tags: grandmaster, chess-olympiad

Being an Italian, I am following my team at the Batumi Olympiad, and I was disappointed in seeing that GM Godena had just lost to a mere Candidate Master rated 500 ELO lower (Italy - Nepal). Then I realized that he resigned in a much better position Why?

This is the final position:

```
[Title "Godena vs. Lama, Batumi - 2018"]
[FEN "r3r3/1q2pp1k/7p/1b1PN1p1/4Pn2/4Q2P/3N1PP1/1R2R1K1 w - - 4 30"]
```

Here is full the Game:

```
[Title "Godena vs. Lama, Batumi - 2018"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 g6 4. O-O Bg7 5. c3 Nf6 6. Re1 a6 7. Bxc6 dxc6 8. h3 O-O 9. d4 Qa5 10. Bg5 h6 11. Bh4 Re8 12. Nbd2 cxd4 13. cxd4 Be6 14. Bg3 Rad8 15. Be5 Nh5 16. Bxg7 Kxg7 17. Qc1 Qb5 18. Qc3 Kh7 19. a4 Qb6 20. b4 Qc7 21. b5 axb5 22. axb5 Qc8 23. bxc6 bxc6 24. Rac1 Nf4 25. Qe3 g5 26. Ne5 Qb7 27. Nxc6 Ra8 28. d5 Bd7 29. Ne5 Bb5 30. Rb1
```

Comment: Indeed, it's strange. On ChessBomb https://www.chessbomb.com/arena/2018-batumi-chess-olympiad/07-Godena_Michele-Lama_Himal, Stockfish 8 evaluates the final position as winning for white. And white still had 1m17s left on the clock. Perhaps the game continued and the transmission failed?

Comment: You are perhaps right, especially since White's resignation comes after he has just moved, which is very unusual indeed. GM Godena should not be in his best shape in this tournament, since he lost to a FM too, the round earlier.

Comment: From Italian coverage of the Olympiad I now read that Godena, evidently in bad shape, lost on time.

Comment: Maybe he was sick?  I resigned a game once because I was sick.   I hear that Tal was often sick, so not a complete explanation.

Comment: The Game was lost on time in zeitnot after further moves. I don't know if he was sick, but he was certainly in bad shape, he lost to a FM the round earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transmissions can be inaccurate in real-time. I once saw 1.e4 a6 in a Follow Chess game, but it was actually 1. e4 c5.

In the real game, GM Godena lost on time.